# Set autotools library filename and reference it later on

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake, libtool

I'm using `autotools` to build a library which will later be loaded by another program. This library has to have a `.so` extension to it regardless of the platform I'm on (this is a requirement imposed by the program loading it), and I'd also like it to not have a version specifier. How can I set the output name of such a library?

This is what `Makefile.am` looks like

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = mylib.la
mylib_la_SOURCES = mylib.c
mylib_la_CPPFLAGS = $(LTDLINCL)
mylib_la_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) $(LIBFFI_CFLAGS)
LDADD = $(LIBLTDL) -dlopen self
```

Reading through the `libtool` manpage, it seems I need to set `-install_name`, but I don't see it referenced in the generated `Makefile` anywhere.

I also need to be able to reference this library's output directory elsewhere in the `Makefiles` (for testing purposes), is there a variable containing its basename or full path?

Comment: If you want to to express an `-install_name` option to `libtool` then you would do so by putting it into the variable `mylib_la_LDFLAGS`, or maybe into `AM_LDFLAGS`.  You not yet having done so, I don't see why you would expect to see any such option in the generated Makefiles.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever used `autotools`. Coming from `cmake`, this seemed like the correct behaviour of things. **Edit:** `-install_name` does not do what I wanted anyway.

Comment: In that case, it may not be obvious to you that if you modify your `configure.ac` file or one of your `Makefile.am` files then you should afterward run `autoreconf`.  It may also not be clear to you that you use the Autotools to build your build system from such files, but the result -- `configure` script, supporting scripts, and maybe `Makefile.in` files -- is independent of the Autotools.  You don't need the Autotools themselves to configure or build the software.

Comment: Have you considered not trying to fight the system?  Why not just create a right-named symlink on those systems where the standard shared-library extension is different from `.so` (*i.e.* on Mac)?

Comment: Thanks, but I understand how the tools work. I have used them many times before to build software and have found myself reading through the generated scripts in order to debug them. I run `autoreconf` and `configure` after every change. As for the symlink, the idea has occurred to me, but I intend to package the library as an `.so` anyway, so maybe a `cp` would be better. Either way, I still don't know how to obtain the full path of the binary (or its directory).

Comment: Ok, well that's a different question.  The ultimate *install* location of the targets named by `lib_LTLIBRARIES` is given by the `lib` part of that variable's name.  It can be set at `configure` time and / or `make` time, and within the Makefile it can be read from variable `$(libdir)`.  On the other hand, the *build* location of the files associated with `mylib.la` is pretty much an implementation detail, but you will probably find them in a `.libs/` subdirectory of the build directory.

Comment: So how would I go about testing my software? I need to know where things are when I run them and I'm pretty sure everyone else who uses Autotools does too. Is `make check` run after `make install`? In CMake I can get the location of any target at any time during the build, so I can easily configure testing scripts/targets to use it.

Comment: You can build and run test programs without installing the software, and without explicit knowledge of the location of the actual shared library.  You can do it manually via (GNU) `libtool`, but more easily by describing the test programs to Automake.  Use `foo_LDADD = mylib.la` to specify that program `foo` needs to be linked against the library.

Comment: I don't want to link against it though, I want to load it with a `dlopen` like interface.

Comment: I forgot to mention I updated my `LDFLAGS` with `-module` and `-avoid-version`, which seem to do exactly what I want.

Comment: `-module` is indeed the thing to use if you want to be able to dlopen the resulting library, or if you don't want its name to begin with "lib".  And `-avoid-version` is indeed the right thing to avoid having the version in the target file's name.  They often go together.

Comment: To test `dlopen()`ing the result, you have several alternatives.  Large among them are  (1) Install to the final directory and test it there; (2) install to a staging area, maybe even under your build directory, and test from there (see [DESTDIR](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/DESTDIR.html)); (3) find where libtool is putting the `.so` (probably under hidden directory `.libs/`) and just use it there, regardless of the inherent dependency on implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set the output name of such a library?

The output name of the library will be the name given in `lib_LTLIBRARIES` without the suffix `.a`. It will generate by default a shared library - `.so`. Thus, you do not need to specify anything else.

> I also need to be able to reference this library's output directory elsewhere in the Makefiles (for testing purposes), is there a variable containing its basename or full path?

The variable `$(libdir)` or `@libdir@` in the Makefile will point to the full path of the library directory.